# How to include empty classes in reduce.Region in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, reduceregion

I use the `.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1)})` option to get the sum of the areas in my image per class. The only problem is that some classes are not present in certain regions. The output of this `.reduceRegion` leaves out those classes, whereas I would like the output to still include the class and says that the sum is 0. Does anyone know how to get this?

My script can be found here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/908693bb53ad9596b67b96574286d1d8

```
var province = 'Bukidnon'
var nClusters = 8

var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");
var filter = ee.Filter.inList('ADM2_NAME', [province]);
var filteredArea = fromList.filter(filter);
var roi=filteredArea.geometry();
Map.centerObject(roi)
var table = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_EN', province))

var startDateStr = '2018-06-01'
var endDateStr = '2019-06-01'
var startDate = ee.Date(startDateStr);
var endDate =  ee.Date(endDateStr);
var startEnd = ee.String(startDateStr).cat(ee.String(endDateStr))
var sentinel1_vh = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  .select('VH')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10))
  //.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(roi));

// For month
var month = 1;
// Calculating number of intervals
var months = endDate.difference(startDate,'month').divide(month).toInt();
// Generating a sequence 
var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, months); 

var sequence_s1 = sequence.map(function(num){
    num = ee.Number(num);
    var Start_interval = startDate.advance(num.multiply(month), 'month');
    var End_interval = startDate.advance(num.add(1).multiply(month), 'month');
    var subset = sentinel1_vh.filterDate(Start_interval,End_interval);
    return subset.median().set('system:time_start',Start_interval);
});

var byMonthYearS1 = (ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(sequence_s1)).filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));
var multibands1 = byMonthYearS1.toBands().clip(roi);

// Reset the bandnames
var namess1 = multibands1.bandNames();
// rename the bandnames 
var nMonthss1 =(namess1.length()).subtract(1) ;

var pertamas1=sentinel1_vh.first();
var systimes1=pertamas1.get('system:time_start');
var startDates1 =(ee.Date(systimes1));
// get a list of time strings to pass into a dictionary later on
var monLists1 = ee.List.sequence(0, nMonthss1).map(function (n) {
  return startDates1.advance(n, 'month').format('yyyy-MM');
})
var multibands1 = multibands1.rename(monLists1).clip(roi);//
var combinedband = multibands1;

// ********************************************
// unsupervised learning / clustering
// ********************************************

var training = combinedband.sample({
  region: roi,
  scale: 10,
  numPixels: 2000,
  tileScale:8
});


var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(nClusters).train({
  features:training
});

// Cluster the input using the trained clusterer.
var result_cluster =combinedband.cluster(clusterer).byte();
var clusters = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(nClusters).subtract(1)); 
var values0 = ee.List.sequence(1, nClusters)
               
var remapped_cluster = result_cluster.remap(clusters, values0).clip(roi);
var remapped_cluster = remapped_cluster.rename('class')
var rice_mask_multi=multibands1.addBands(remapped_cluster);

//////////////////////////////////////////////
///// supervised learning
//////////////////////////////////////////////

// use all 24 months as training data
var bands = monLists1
var rice_mask_multi = rice_mask_multi.cast({'class': 'int64'})
// use 2000 data points as training set
var training_set = rice_mask_multi.stratifiedSample({
  region: roi,
  classBand: 'class',
  scale: 100,
  geometries: true,
  numPoints: 3200,
  classValues: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  classPoints: [400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400],
  seed: 0
});

var combinedband_train = combinedband;
// Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = combinedband_train.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: training_set,
  // Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
  properties: ['class'],
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 100
});

// Create an SVM classifier with custom parameters.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.libsvm({
  kernelType: 'RBF',
//  cost: 1.5
//  gamma: 0.5
});

// Train the classifier.
var trained = classifier.train(training, 'class', bands);
// Classify the image.
var classified = combinedband.classify(trained);

var n = table.size();

var getKey = function(number){
  return ee.Feature(table.toList(n).get(number)).get('ADM3_EN')
}
var list = ee.List.sequence(0, n.subtract(1));
var keys = list.map(getKey)

// var dic = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, table.geometry().coordinates())
var getRiceMunActual = function(index){
  var geo_mun = ee.Feature(table.toList(120).get(index)).geometry().dissolve();
  var roi_mun_a = rice_mask_multi.clip(geo_mun)
  var rice_actual = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1000000).addBands(remapped_cluster).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1),
  geometry: roi_mun_a.geometry(),
  scale: 100,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
  return rice_actual
}

var riceAreasActual = list.map(getRiceMunActual)
print(riceAreasActual)
```

It's about the last part of the code (from line 135 onwards). I would like that all elements of the object `riceAreasActual` are fo the same length (8 in this case), whereas you can see now that some are of length 7 (index, 5, 6, 9, 10) since in those regions the class with label 2 is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the groups to a dictionary and combine the result for each region with a dictionary of defaults.

```
// Create a dictionary of defaults.
var defaults = ee.Dictionary(ee.List.sequence(1, 8).map(function(n) {
  return [ee.Number(n).format("%d"), 0]
}).flatten())

// Convert a grouped reducer output to a dictionary
var convert = function(groups) {
  return ee.Dictionary(ee.List(groups).map(function(g) {
    g = ee.Dictionary(g)
    return [g.getNumber('group').format("%d"), g.get('sum')]
  }).flatten()).combine(defaults, false)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/987e82b3f1fc8b0b6bd282aa10eab5ef

Comment: Super, thank you so much!